# \hbox cause alignment Error

Tags: math-mode, macros, horizontal-alignment, boxes

I have an issue i can't figure it out, i have a definition like

```
\let\rendsplit@old=\rendsplit@
\def\rendsplit@{%
  \global\setbox\z@\vbox{\hbox{\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}}}%
  \rendsplit@old%
}
```

the equation:

```
\begin{align}\begin{split}{E}_{\varepsilon }\dot{x}\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right)&=Ax\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right)\mathbin{+}B\varphi \left(\vrule height 5.93326pt depth 3.39229pt width 0pty\vrule height 5.93326pt depth 3.39229pt width 0pt\right)\mathbin{+}{B}_{u}u\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right),\label{EEq1}\end{split}\tag*{$\text{(1)}$}\\[5pt]\begin{split}y\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right)&=Cx\left(\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0ptt\vrule height 7.79312pt depth 0.15717pt width 0pt\right),\label{EEq2}\end{split}\tag*{$\text{(2)}$}\end{align}
```

should appear aligned at equal sign but i noticed that no align at equal sign, but after fixing the definition above to be like

```
\let\rendsplit@old=\rendsplit@
\def\rendsplit@{%
  \global\setbox\z@\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}%
  \rendsplit@old%
}
```

the equations aligned correctly at the equal sign.
So my question is, why \hbox command cause error in alignment.

Note: i use \hbox to specify the x and y points before the inside \vbox and after \vbox by some special commands related to DVISVGM tool.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make a complete example.

Comment: you should never make global assignments to box 0 (you could break most latex constructs doing that!)    You give no indication of the intention of the code, nor an example to allow anyone to run it, so I don't know what answer you expect.

Comment: it is best not to load `etex` package in current latex. Your added example is not usable without files I do not have. Can you really not make an example of the problem just using `article` class and `amsmath`  If `chemarr` or `hyperref` are not involved _don't load them_ as they just complicate debugging. if `\input{statement.tex}` is necessary, provide that file, otherwise delete that line, etc.....

Comment: you shouldn't load `epsfig` unless emulating documents from 1985

Answer (score 4):

The original macro does

```
 \vtop{%
            \unvcopy\z@
            \global\setbox8 \lastbox
```

(it should not be doing global assignments to box 8 but ignore that for now)

this strips the last box (row) off the vertical list that was in box 0.

Your redefinition (which *definitely* should not be making global assignments to box 0) does

```
  \global\setbox\z@\vbox{\hbox{\vbox{\unvcopy\z@}}}%
```

which means that box 0 always just has a vertical list of exactly one box, with all the structure inside that box.

So the above code to remove the "last line" will always remove the whole thing.

Without any context, not possible to suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please check my question again i made some edits to it and add a full example.

Comment: @MohamedSayed you have provided an example document (which is an improvement, although still not actually usable as it includes files I don't have) but no indication about the intention of this definition, so other than saying do not do that, I can't suggest what you should do.

Comment: Sorry David i was wrong to add such example with files you don't have. i am sorry again.

Comment: I can't provide you with an example because all of that is related to each other and i am actually not a LaTeX expert so, i thank you for your help and my question now is what is the difference between boxes? you said that global assignment is not right with box 0, really i didn't understand that line and also what is the box8 and box9 and how to use them.

Comment: @MohamedSayed box 0,2,4,6,8 are scratch boxes for temporary _local_ use. box 1,3,5,7,9 are scratch boxes for temporary _global_ use otherwise you should allocate your own box with `\newbox` and then use it consistently for local or global assignments. (There is probably an answer on site about that somewhere)